# Getting (401) UnAuthorized error on some requests not all, but most

Tags: authentication, here-api

I don't think this is a code issue, but we have a list of hundreds of addresses to process. Some return data and we are able to get Long and Lat but most return (401) UnAuthorized errors. What would cause this to happen? We have tried passing Host Headers and everything else, the REST API seems to work better in our development environment but throws way more errors when deployed to our Job Server. Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated. We would like to understand why some calls work and others don't, we pass the same apiKey each time so this is really confusing. Thanks

Here is a code snippet using c# (Work in progress):

```
 //GET THE LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE BASED OFF THE PHYSICAL ADDRESS
String clientAddress = clientRow["home_address"].ToString() + ", " + clientRow["home_city"].ToString() + ", " + clientRow["home_state"].ToString() + ", " + clientRow["home_zip"].ToString();
Logger.Debug("CLIENT ADDRESS: {0}", clientAddress);
String geocoderUri = "https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=" + clientAddress + "&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //KEY REMOVED FOR POSTING ON STACK OVERFLOW
var syncClient = new WebClient();

var content = syncClient.DownloadString(geocoderUri);
//CREATE THE JSON SERIALIZER AND PARSE OUR RESPONSE
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AddressData));
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content)))
{
    var addressData = (AddressData)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    if (addressData.items.Count() > 0)
    {
        //INSERT THE LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE IN DB
        String sLat = addressData.items[0].position.lat.ToString();
        String sLong = addressData.items[0].position.lng.ToString();
        Logger.Debug("CLIENT GEOLOCATION - Longitude: {0} Latitude: {1}", sLong, sLat);
        insertLatLong(sLat, sLong, clientRow["clientID"].ToString(), 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the addresses shall be the cause of the 401 errors, without affected addresses and some side snippet it will not be possible to help further, I am afraid

Comment: The addresses will not result in a server 401 error from the Here API, this is also not possible to share due to it being PHI data (I work in healthcare). Code snippets will not explain it either, but I will update with our development code. Thanks for your reply, I appreciate the assistance

Comment: Could it be that you are using a freemium account and you are reaching your limit for how frequently you are calling the API and you are getting throttled? Can you confirm what kind of account you have?

Comment: I agree with @PersistentPlants you are probably reaching the rate limit, so you randomly receive a couple of 401 responses. How many requests per second are you making to the Geocoder API?

Comment: I am on the freemium account but didn't see a rate limit, just the monthly limit. Do you happen to know what the rate limit is? I'm still not able to find it on the site or thru a google search.

Comment: According to the documentation, when the rate limit is exceeded, I should be receiving a 429 error and not a 401.  (HTTP 429 Too Many Requests)

Comment: I ended up switching from WebClient to HttpClient and everything is now working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try to use RestSharp lib for rest api?

Please see below sample code.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q="+ clientAddress);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer YOUR TOKEN");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: We switched to HttpClient and everything is working now. Thanks for you response.